# JSF and automatic reload of Facelets files

Tags: jsf, facelets, mojarra, jrebel

I had some problems with hot-reloading Facelets files using JRebel, Spring, JSF Mojarra 2.0.3 and WebLogic 10.3.

JRebel reloads regular Java classes and js/css files under /WebContent successfully, but not JSF's .xhtml files. A full republish was necessary to get xhtml files updated on the server.

By trial and error I finally got it to work by adding some facelets parameters to web.xml and creating a custom ResourceResolver as described [in this blog post](http://www.warski.org/blog/2007/12/instant-facelets-changes-in-xhtml-and-no-redeploying/).

However, I wonder WHY this works, and more specifically:

- Why is a custom ResourceResolver needed?
- Isn't JRebel supposed to handle this by monitoring /WebContent where the xhtml files reside?
- I'm guessing it has something to do with Facelets/JSF compiling xhtml to servlets(?) via FacesServlet which JRebel is unable to detect?

Answer (score 48):

JRebel handles /WebContent folder changes.

The problem is that Facelets do caching and do not reread changed files. To force reload specify one of the following parameters in `web.xml`.

**JSF 2+** (Facelets 2+):

```xml
<!-- Set the project stage to "Development", "UnitTest", "SystemTest", or "Production". -->
<!-- An optional parameter that makes troubleshooting development stage errors much easier. -->
<!-- You should remove this context parameter before deploying to production or override via Server's JNDI config! -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This will automatically set the "Facelets refresh period" configuration to 0, hereby effectively disabling the Facelets cache.

Or, if you don't want to change the project stage, then

```xml
<!-- Time in seconds that Facelets should be checked for changes since last request. A value of -1 disables auto-refresh. -->
<!-- You should remove this context parameter before deploying to production or use PROJECT_STAGE instead! -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

For Faces 4.x the `javax.` prefix should be `jakarta.` instead, like so `jakarta.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` and `jakarta.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD`.

---

For **JSF 1.2** (Facelets 1.x) the equivalent parameters are:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

More on JSF context params: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/JSF_Guide/en-US/html/jsf.reference.html#standard.config.params

That custom resource resolver is not needed in your case. That resource resolver is just a tricky way to get xhtml files from custom file system folder. In your case JRebel does that (and even more).

Comment: I believe that JRebel already implicitly does that. At least, here it does. Note that your context params are Facelets 1.x specific and that OP is using Facelets 2.x.

Comment: @Balusc Thanks for reply, answer updated to be Facelets 2.x specific.

Comment: Setting `javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD` to `0` and `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` to `Development` does not seem to trigger updated templates with JRebel on JSF 2.0.4 and WebLogic 10.3.

Comment: @uggedal OP has noted that 'finally got it to work by adding some facelets parameters to web.xml and creating a custom ResourceResolver '. I don't know whether it works for him without custom resource resolver.

Comment: Gotta love stack overflow. `javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD` worked perfectly for me. JBoss 4, JSF2.

Comment: Our team uses Glassfish 3/IceFaces and we had FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD set to -1 for quite a while.  Setting it to 0 enabled hot-reloading XHTML.

Comment: this change is a must in order to use jsf with jrebel

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I fixed this for me:

1. Verify that `facelets` plugin is enabled in your JRebel settings &
2. Verify that you're using `Project Stage` **`Development`** in your `web.xml`