# Configure javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD directly on JBoss server

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, web.xml, jboss-4.2.x

We have an existing application (*JSF 1.2*), packaged as an ear, running on *JBoss 4.2*. We use *JRebel*, and to be able to automatically detect changes in our xhtml files we needed to [disable caching for Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512414/jsf-and-automatic-reload-of-xhtml-files) by adding this to our web.xml:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I would however prefer if this parameter could be done directly on the JBoss server, is this possible? If so, where do I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to `/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/conf/web.xml` the same way as you would do in webapp's own `/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

Comment: is there any way to force cache refresh via Java?