# Reload JSF changes with JRebel

Tags: jsf, jrebel

Although **JRebel** can reload Java class changes in my project, it can not reload **JSF** changes. When I change a JSF file I can not see any logs etc.
Here is my *rebel.xml*:

```
<classpath>
    <dir name="${projectDir}/classes">
    </dir>
</classpath>

<web>
    <link target="/WEB-INF">
        <dir name="${projectDir}/war/conf">
        </dir>
    </link>
</web>
```

All JSF files are in *${projectDir}/war/*. I use **JBoss** and **IntelliJ IDEA**. In the project, Ant creates an ear file and deploys it to JBoss.

How can I use *JRebel to reload JSF files*?  Should web tag in *rebel.xml* point JSF files or compiled XHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar problem, and for me it was the parameter `javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD` which needs to be set to 0. The parameter is set in the *web.xml*.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

There is a good blog entry [here](http://my-java-planet.blogspot.se/2012/04/how-to-jsf-20-application-configuration.html) describing the different available configuration parameters:

> Time in seconds that facelets should be checked for changes since last request. When a page is requested, what interval in seconds should the compiler check for changes. If you don't want the compiler to check for changes once the page is compiled, then use a value of -1. Setting a low refresh period helps during development to be able to edit pages in a running application.

So in short, setting the value to `0` during development should enable immediate reloading of the files.

Comment: It is better to set the PROJECT_STAGE to development during development. This also sets the refresh to 0 and lots of other interesting information shows up then when you make errors

Comment: @Kukeltje Fair enough. Shouldn't you add that as your own answer?

Comment: No, go ahead, add it to your answer

Comment: I've applied the configuration here;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512414/jsf-and-automatic-reload-of-xhtml-files
But I still have same problem.
Thank you for suggestion.