# Intellij Hot swap webapp folder not working

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am running a simple Maven web application using spring. My project structure is as following

```
src-main-java
src-main-webapp
```

My HTML file in the webapp folder. When I do `update class and resource` in debug mode it updates my Java classes but not my HTML files.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue. You may need disable cache in your view resolver. then it should work just fine.

e.g. `resolver.setCacheable(false);` for Spring or ThymeLeaf application.

Answer (score 0):

Use exploded artifact which name ends with .war or .ear.

See more here:
[IntelliJ hot swapping classes, but not JSF pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316925/intellij-hot-swapping-classes-but-not-jsf-pages/33344839#33344839)