# IntelliJ Idea 15 - How to "update resources" without restarting server?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

When I click to the `debug button` after the server is started to `update resources with/without classes`, the prompt that I shared below is displayed. How can I `update resources` without restarting server?

ps. I am using `Tomcat` as a server.

[image]

Edit: I have already set the option `update resources` in the server preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use 'Update application' action, by default Ctrl + F10.

Comment: on my macbook with extra keyboard nothing happens: neither CTRL+F10 nor CMD+F10

Comment: @DirkSchumacher: check the key shortcut 'Search actions' dialogue.

Comment: There is no option to automatically update application on lose of focus in debug like in running or?!

Comment: @cljk I'm not sure I understand the question... Let's assume I do and you mean losing focus of IDEA's window. But the focus has nothing to do, does it? I mean: you'd like to restart the app or update the classes after you make some changes to the source code, config files, environment, etc. What has it common with the focus?

Comment: In normal run mode there is an option to update resources on focus lost of the Idea window. In debug this option is missing. But I got used to the keyboard shortcut (was it ctrl-F10 ?) ... perhaps I'll purchase again a JRebel license

Comment: @DirkSchumache try CMD+fn+F10

Answer (score 1):

You're explicitly trying to restart the server (via clicking on "Debug" while the server is running).

Instead of that you can either use "Update" action from "Run > Update ... application" (which you've already configured to update resources) or re-deploy the artifact.

Btw updating of resources is somehow tricky, if it's not working see my other post on this topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33344839/5060066

Comment: no, it was not working in this way previously. For previous versions of Idea, update dialog was displayed when use the hotkey Shift+Alt+D (or when the debug button is clicked)

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**

- In *IDEA 2020*, `edit configuration` -> `running application update policies` ->

  - `on 'update' action`, change to: `Update classes and resources`
  - `on frame deactivation`, change to: `Update classes and resources`
- Start in **debug** mode.

Then each time change code, it will try to redeploy, it may take a second.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way can update resources without restart server.

In Server -> Development you can see the project, with the name `your_project_name.war`.

There are 3 buttons. Push the Deploy button to Redeploy the project.Like the pic follow:

Then refresh the page. You will see the change.

[image]

Comment: As far as I see, it **redeploys** the web app instead of **hot deploy**; so takes lots of more time than just using **update** or **frame deactivation** events.

Comment: Yes, like I said `Push the Deploy button to Redeploy the project.`. I want hot swap too, but I've not find a way out.So this is the best way to me.

Comment: Doesn't work. Update Application means redeploy project or restart server.(Intellij idea 15, macOS 10.12)

Comment: If I recall correctly, there should be other options such as `"update resources"`, `"update classes with resources"` on the `server configuration` user interface.

Comment: If *hot deploy* does not work (like for me when running an exploded EAR file Wildfly after changing properties files) then *redeploy* is way faster (10 secs) than stopping and starting the server (60 secs). It's not optimal, but better than a restart.