# intellij webapp hot deploy changes to html files

Tags: intellij-idea

I have added a tomcat server and in my maven ui project I do a maven install. Then I start the tomcat server and it deploys my ui project as a exploded war. Now if I make changes to a js, css or html file should be be seen in the target web app as they do not need to be compiled. Right now I don't see the changes. Is there a setting for it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the your artifact is build when making the project (File > Project Structure > Artifacts > YOUR_EXPLODED_ARTIFACT > Build on make).

Furthermore, use exploded artifact which name ends with .war or .ear.

See more here:
[IntelliJ hot swapping classes, but not JSF pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316925/intellij-hot-swapping-classes-but-not-jsf-pages/33344839#33344839)

Comment: Build on make does not work if the project is currently running, which is my case.

Comment: did you check the exploded artifact name? Also, Tomcat should be started in debug mode, and in it configuration the setting "On 'Update' action" should be "Update classes and resources"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Tomcat uses the target folder of maven as the code for webapp. Hence doing an install, moves all code to the target folder and if the file is js, html, css than it gets picked up, when you revist the page.