# Edit XHTML of a deployed JSF project in glassfish

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I have a web application I'd like to edit while it's already deployed.
The part I'd like to edit is inside `...applications/myapplication/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/*.xhtml`.

I have a tool that I use to generate these XHTML files and insert them into the aforementioned directory. In a production environment actually these XHTML files are part of a jar project included as a dependency in the main web application.

But what I need is to make hot deploy during development.

I can do it by removing the jar dependency and adding the XHTML in the directory mentioned above. But updating it later doesn't do the job.

Any idea?

Comment: I modified xhtml files in production environment with vim. Without changing the jar. If you have a command line on the production server it's no problem. Glassfish recognizes the change with the next access.

Comment: @Holger: Glassfish only recognizes changes IF JSF in your webapp is configured to reload. For production this is can be a delay. And it is never good to update pages inside your webapp. JSF is configurable to have e resource loader that loads pages from outside the war (e.g. a database or different filesystem). Better to use that. And for this there are duplicates in Stackoverflow

Comment: @Kukeltje  Thanks.

Comment: @Kukeltje How do I configure JSF to reload?

Comment: normally by using google.... But I did that for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512414/jsf-and-automatic-reload-of-xhtml-files

Comment: @Kukeltje Yeah I found that using Google. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IntellijIDEA, just go to the configuration of glassfish server and select "Update Resources" on "Frame Deactivation".