# How to create a new JSF Web application using Eclipse?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I know this question is too old and often asked. But I am new to JSF, and not able to find the exact solution for the same. I am using Eclipse and trying to create a simple JSF application with Prime Faces support.

I tried many steps. I need help in exact steps in creating an application. Initially I tried by creating dynamic web application and selecting JSF 2.2 and importing Apache Myfaces 2.2 jar. It worked fine but I have to restart the Tomcat each and every time when code are changed.

Well on the other side I imported some of my JSF web application of my organization, it works as expected, but when I placed its jar in the new project and followed the same steps, it gives some error. Sometimes, tomcat failed to start, sometimes its giving an error 'Error in thread 'main''. Though there is no java resource present in my project.

What exact steps to follow and what core jars are needed in creating jsf with prime faces support. And it would be great help if anybody can explain the difference between placing the jars in java build path and placing the jars in Web>lib folder.

Comment: _"It worked fine but"_ So you were able "to create a new JSF Web application using Eclipse"... _" I have to restart the Tomcat each and every time when code are changed. "_ Why not search stackoverflow or google for this specific part. **"JSF automatically reload changes tomcat"** (which will result in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512414/jsf-and-automatic-reload-of-xhtml-files) ... Regarding your last question, (1 question per question is common/good practice in stackoverflow btw, ) please start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info or https://jsf.zeef.com/bauke.scholtz

Comment: "It worked fine but", here I imported the project which was already developed by old teams, its works fine. I just need the proper steps to follow and the core jars needed in creating the application.

Comment: Then look at all the other links I provided...(or look at the structure of the imported project) and _"**Sometimes**, tomcat failed to start, **sometimes** its giving **an** error 'Error in thread 'main'. "_ Is not something we can actually work with/help with... Try being more specific (and posting errors in google is very, very helpful)