# Tomcat does not reload jsp pages

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, ide, tomcat9

Sometimes a problem of this nature arises.

I use Tomcat and Inteliji Idea. I make changes in jsp pages, and when I deploy the project in a browser, Tomcat opens the old version of the jsp page, and if I make changes in the servlet, the behavior of the jsp pages changes, but the visual component does not change.

What to do so that the volume normally reloads the page ???

Comment: Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html. If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There may be some caching enabled for the framework you are using. So it's not possible to answer your question without additional details.

Comment: thanks. please, Write your comment in answer. i will note right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the JSP reloading to work you need to use Exploded artifact configuration in IntelliJ IDEA and use the Update action (either explicitly, or by configuring the IDE to perform the Update on frame deactivation). The Update action has to be set to update the classes and resources. More details can be found in [this document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html).

Some frameworks like JSF may introduce caching which will prevent the Update from working properly. In this case you'll need to disable the framework caching. For JSF caching configuration please [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7514528/104891).